# Why would OAuth2 authorization code be given without displaying the login UI?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

Consider sample OAuth2 flow: we go through OAuth2 authentication for a web server app.
Authorization code request is being sent - user is presented with "log in" UI.
After he inputs credentials - we get authorization code and use it for access/refresh tokens.
Let's say there is a business reason to re-authenticate the user before his token expires.

For that - authorization code request is issud again - however this time it is not resulting in "log in" UI and new authorization code is granted without user input. Why's that?

Why that happens? Is it some state stored on client's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the OAuth server thought the user had already logged in and that re-authentication could be omitted. So, probably some state is cached on your browser for the login session.

If the OAuth server supports OpenID Connect, try to add 'prompt=login' parameter to the authorization request and you will always see the login UI. See "[3.1.2.1. Authentication Request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)" in [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) for details.